# capturing move events with IE10 and windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows, html, mouse, tablet

I'm trying to capture signatures using a html5 client on windows 8 touchscreen tablet. 
I've tried using http://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad , but rather than the smooth curves it captures on the desktop with a mouse, it only captures the occasional dot .

I set up a html5 canvas and brushed a finger over it on the tablet, capturing mouse over, mouse enter and mouse down.

It seems only the start of the movement sets off mouse enter/ mouse over events.

I tried again with a stylus and got the same result.

I tried using a line of a hundred or so divs, same result.

Tried using chrome instead, same result

This makes sense (sort of) as the tablet doesn't have a mouse, but I need to capture the mouse move events of a pressed finger/stylus to capture a signature.

Has anyone solved this ?

Comment: i think you are missing something somewhere because i just tried and it works. For the record, i used my finger to draw it. Have you tried the demo directly? --> http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/accept/

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Windows 8 IE10 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

Just add that to signaturepad.css file on the .sigWrapper and the thomasjbradley control should work.

It appears the touch events that IE10 is registering to is breaking the event listeners for the mouse events on that control.

Answer (score 0):

Try these events MSPointerDown, MSPointerMove, MSPointerUp and many more mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh465891.aspx

These events work in Windows Phone 8 but I am not sure if they work in Windows 8 Tablet.